# Making approve/deny links active for To: recipients but not CC

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, smtp

I have a webform form that was written in ASP.Net using VB.
The form has text fields that ask for common nonsensitive information (Name, current date, position, etc.).  There is also a drop-down list that contains email address for certain department.

Once the form is completed, and an department email has been chosen from the drop down list, this information is emailed to 5 separate email addresses. The email chosen from the drop down list will be added to the email as a carbon copied (CC:) recipient. When the the user clicks the Submit button, it generates an email that will display the information from the form, as well as two links, one Approval link an one Deny link, where each link will go to two different URLs respectively.

Again, this email is sent out to the 5 main recipients and one carbon copied email recipient chosen by the user in the drop down list on the form.

Here are my questions:

1. Programmatically, is there a way to have the two URL links in the email disabled, maybe even hidden, from the carbon copied email recipient only when the email is sent out? Only the 5 main email recipients will see and click on either link.
2. If not possible programmatically, is there a way to do have this done by manipulating Active Directory or Exchange Server?
3. By doing this, is this violating any software compliance agreements.

Please note, that is only a hypothetical situation. The webform and it's setup has been created, and can send email via SMTP, but not in the way as mentioned in the hypothetical questions I just asked. I am just checking if what I asked is even possible and how can I approach it. I've done some research, but haven't found anything saying that this is possible. Whatever opinion you can give me will be very appreciated.

Comment: No, that is not possible. You are only sending _one_ email message here, and that does not magically change based upon who is receiving it. You would have to send a _different email_, if you want a recipient to see _different email content_.

Answer (score 0):

When the links are clicked, they could go to a page requiring user authentication.  If the user does not have a cookie indicating they are authenticated, as someone with permission to take the action the link target would have, the user is given a message indicating they need to log in as such a person, and if they are not logged in at all, form fields or a link to where they can log in.

You could also have your e-mail sending script send slightly different e-mails to different recipients.  This would be the solution if you don't want one user to even see the links/available actions included in messages to others.